# How "View" behaves in terms of memory

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have a question related to "View" in SQL
If I created a View, would it disappear when I restart my PC? "I have a local DB"

I've searched a lot of documents online and they almost say that it gets removed, However, I have created a View and restarted my PC and the view is still there (isn't removed)
I'm wondering if you could help me with how a view and a temporary table behave.

Regards

Comment: "*I've searched a lot of documents online*" - why read random posts on the internet if [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) gives you all the information you need?

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, a `VIEW` is something kind of like a macro or shortcut.  Basically, it stores the parsed form of a query so that it can be called with a simple name.  The idea is that the output of a query is a table -- therefore, it would be logically simpler to give a table-name to that output, and you can `SELECT * FROM <table-name>`.  This is what a `VIEW` ultimately is, and it is created by `CREATE VIEW <table-name> AS <query that would produce table-name>`.

With that in mind, this shortcut is not something that is persisted to disk, but simply available to users for sake of simplicity and convenience, and this shortcut lives on between reboots and restarts.  More information about `VIEW` can be [found in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-views.html)

A `TEMPORARY TABLE`, however, is a table that exists only until the end of your session.  It can be seen only by the current user of the session, and is discarded at the end of that session.  It does not live on between reboots/restarts.  However, it is persisted to disk (but is immediately removed after the session ends).  Conceivably, if the machine is unplugged and there is no chance for Postgres to drop the temporary table, it could live on, but would not be accessible by any other session.  Autovacuum will ultimately remove that table when the autovacuum process begins.  More information about `TEMPORARY TABLE` can also be [found in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

Finally, a `MATERLIALIZED VIEW` is something like a `VIEW`, but is not simply a shortcut for a longer query.  Rather, it is a snapshot of a query that is stored on disk, accessible by multiple sessions, and lives on between reboots/restarts.  With `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, it is possible to get the output of a query and store it for future use, potentially saving you from having to re-run a really long query that takes minutes or hours to complete.  More information about `MATERIALIZED VIEW` can be [found in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)

Comment: One nit I have to pick: it is not the text of the query that is stored for a view.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i'm totally open to suggestions for edits, if you don't mind elaborating ‍♂️ I was under the impression it's the text of the query that gets stored, since if you `SELECT * FROM pg_views`, you get the text of the query in the `definition` column -- `SELECT * FROM pg_class` for the view reveals `relfilenode == 0`, meaning there's nothing stored on disk for the view relation itself ‍♂️

Comment: `pg_views` is a view - look at its definition :^) A view is implemented as a query rewrite rule. Look into `pg_rewrite`, that's where the view definition is actually stored.